# why curl_easy_send does't return timeout when network is lost

Tags: c++, timeout, libcurl

I wrote a application like the sendrecv sample of libcur(the sample url is:http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sendrecv.html).
the difference is that 
my app repeat send/receive forever in a loop thread. add set other parameters :

```
    code =curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
    code =curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1L);
    code =curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, 1L);  
    //code =curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);//200 milli secs
    code =curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1L);
```

but when the network is lost,such as the cable is pulled out from netcard interface. the  curl_easy_send is always return CURLE_OK .This seems that the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT has no effect. Is there any wrong of usage or other problems ? What should to do if i want to know the network lost immediately.

Comment: Perhaps i have some wrong understand of libcurl. maybe curl_easy_send only invoke the send method of BSD Socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT has no effect on curl_easy_send().

Comment: What should i do ? Do some check in application?such as heartbeat mechanism.